# HighCharts layout algorithm

Tags: highcharts

Given the following snippet:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'networkgraph',
        marginTop: 80
    },
    title: {
        text: 'DragDrop Fail'
    },
   
    plotOptions: {
        networkgraph: {
            keys: ['from', 'to'],
            layoutAlgorithm: {
                enableSimulation: false,
                integration: 'euler',
            }
        },
       
    },
    series: [{
        id: 'language-tree',
        marker: {
            radius: 13
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            textPath: {
                enabled: true
            },
            linkFormat: '',
            allowOverlap: true
        },
        data: [
            ['Proto Indo-European', 'Balto-Slavic'],
        ]
    }]
});
```

```css
#container {
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/networkgraph.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/draggable-points.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

How can I explain the following fact:

- Proto Indo-European can be moved "as the user want", without affecting its parent
- Balto-Slavic cannot be moved without affecting Proto Indo-European